# Can you help me to identify this IC?

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, driver

I need help to identify this IC:

[image]

Context, truck gate driver:

[image]

Comment: From a TV or other audio/visual device?

Comment: "9718" is possibly 1997, 18th week.

Comment: why do you need to identify that IC? ... what problem will that solve?

Comment: Could it be 8k x 8 SRAM, 
12 address lines + 8 datalines + 2 for power, leaves 2 control lines for enable en read/write

Comment: @hennep 8K needs 13 address lines, so that would be a bit difficult to fit in a 24-pin component. Unless it’s some kind of ROM rather than RAM.

Comment: Can we get good shots of the whole board, too and bottom? And what exactly is a truck gate driver? Does this control some kind of electric motor? What are the inputs and outputs, any communication ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES2 (European Silicon Structures) was a company that made fast-turn custom chips using (then cutting-edge) electron beam and CAD technology.

So I don't think you're going to get any useful information from other than the OEM documents for whatever product that thing came  out of. Image from [Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6970428321339744256?commentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A6970428321339744256%2C6971160690812149760%29&replyUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A6970428321339744256%2C6972606309464477698%29).

[image]